# Is there an Image.point() method in PIL that allows you to operate on all three channels at once?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to write a point filter that is based on the red, green and blue channels for each pixel, but it appears that this might fall short of `point()`'s abilities -- it seems that it operates on a single pixel in a single channel at a time. I'd like to do something like this:

```
def colorswap(pixel):
    """Shifts the channels of the image."""
    return (pixel[1], pixel[2], pixel[0])
image.point(colorswap)
```

Is there an equivalent method that lets me use a filter that takes in a 3-tuple of RGB values and output a new 3-tuple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `load` method to get fast access to all the pixels.

```
def colorswap(pixel):
    """Shifts the channels of the image."""
    return (pixel[1], pixel[2], pixel[0])

def applyfilter(image, func):
    """ Applies a function to each pixel of an image."""
    width,height = im.size
    pixel = image.load()
    for y in range(0, height):
        for x in range(0, width):
            pixel[x,y] = func(pixel[x,y])

applyfilter(image, colorswap)
```

Comment: The `image.load()` method is pretty much what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Based on the responses to date, I'd guess the answer is 'no'.

But you could always employ numpy to do this kind of work efficiently:

```
def colorswap(pixel):
    """Shifts the channels of the image."""
    return (pixel[1], pixel[2], pixel[0])

def npoint(img, func):
    import numpy as np
    a = np.asarray(img).copy()
    r = a[:,:,0]
    g = a[:,:,1]
    b = a[:,:,2]
    r[:],g[:],b[:] = func((r,g,b))
    return Image.fromarray(a,img.mode)

img = Image.open('test.png')
img2 = npoint(img, colorswap)
img2.save('test2.png')
```

---

Bonus:  It looks like the Image class is not read-only, which means you can make your new `npoint` function feel even more like `point` (not recommended unless like confusing people):

```
Image.Image.npoint = npoint

img = Image.open('test.png')
img2 = img.npoint(colorswap)
```